# How to remove black background on awesome_print

Tags: ruby-on-rails, awesomeprint

I'm using the great [awesome_print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) gem in a Rails application. It is working ok except the colored text is against a black background and a bit hard to read. I'd like to keep the colors but without the black background.

[image]

I can see how the nodes can be colored, but how can I easily remove the black background?

Answer (score 1):

This did the job

```
kbd {
    -moz-background-clip:border;
    -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
    -moz-background-origin:padding;
    background:#EEEEEE none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border:none;
    color:#000000;
    padding:2px 1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```